# Override Record's View Action to open a Lightning Component inside Salesforce1 App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, action, salesforce1-app

I want to redirect user to a custom lightning component which would look like record details page with some other functionalities.

Currently, Salesforce doesn't provide any inbuilt functionality to override Standard View Action to a Lightning Component. I was looking into a feature where I can redirect user to Component from my Visualforce Page.

I have tried navigateToComponent but it is not working inside SF1, also as per the documentation it is not an official supported method from salesforce.

Please suggest any alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: I actually create a lightning component tab that contains list of custom object records and later it is getting redirected to custom component on click of record link. Please let me know if you found solution of your problem it will reduce 80% of my coding.

Answer (score 1):

Winter'17 release has the feature you asked. You can override the view action of objects by going to the corresponding object page. The lightning components added will not affect the salesforce classic or lightning experience view. It has impact only on Salesforce1. 
[image] Screenshot of object page